# When one field doesn't equal another field then show a completely different field

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

First time asking a question and have learned a lot from this forum.  I work in a weird industry and we are using NetSuite.  I am having a hard time coming up with a criteria or formula for what I am trying to do.  On any sales order we have the Business Source who could be the listing agent or the selling agent for a property.  The business source is not always the listing agent or always the selling agent.  So I am trying to do a search where (excuse the bad coding example):

If business source is the listing agent, then show the selling agent
If business source is the selling agent, then show the listing agent

From a sales perspective, we want to reach out to the other agent, even if they didn't direct the order our way, and thank them for working with us.

I hope I was somewhat clear...and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add a line in the Results tab and select `Formula (text)` under the Field column.  In the Formula column add:

```
CASE WHEN {custbody_business_source} = {custbody_listing_agent} THEN {custbody_selling_agent} ELSE {custbody_listing_agent} END
```

You will need to replace the fields in braces `{}` with the correct IDs for the fields you're using.  I have assumed that these fields all pull from the same list of records (contacts or customers) for the information they contain.  It probably won't work, for example, if one is a select (List/Record) field and the others are Free Text.  This simply compares the Business Source field with (arbitrarily) the Listing Agent and returns the Selling Agent if there's a match, otherwise it returns the Listing Agent.  Note that this means the Listing Agent will be returned in any other circumstances also; for example if one of the compared fields is empty.

You could match the Business Source against both the agent fields explicitly and return some other value when neither match by extending the CASE statement a little:

```
CASE WHEN {custbody_business_source} = {custbody_listing_agent} THEN {custbody_selling_agent} WHEN {custbody_business_source} = {custbody_selling_agent} THEN {custbody_listing_agent} ELSE {somethingelse} END
```

or by using a `DECODE` instead:

```
DECODE({custbody_business_source}, {custbody_listing_agent}, {custbody_selling_agent}, {custbody_selling_agent}, {custbody_listing_agent}, {somethingelse})
```

`DECODE` has the following signature:

```
DECODE({expr}, search, result, [search, result]..., [default])
```

It compares `expr` with each `search` value one by one.  If it finds a match it returns the corresponding `result`. If no match is found, the default is returned, or null if default is not specified.

Comment: Thank you!  I am new to this and I actually came up with the same formula as you.  Makes me feel proud. Lol!  Now the next challenge.  Is there a way to filter the results for that non-business source agent to only show results when we have never received a sales order from them or haven't received a sales order in the last year?  These would be potential customers that don't use our services or are a first time customer with us that I could create an alert around them.  I really do appreciate your help!

Comment: If the non-business source agent is a Customer record, or a Contact linked to a Customer record, you could filter based on the Date of Last Order (`{lastorderdate}`).  Apart from that suggestion, I'd need more information about how everything's set up and exactly what you need to achieve to help further.  HTH.